# gtk3 cannot resize lxterminal window

Tags: linux, gtk3

getting a lot of (lxterminal) "GtkScrolledWindow 0x8064e0 or a child called gtk_widget_queue_resize() during size_allocate()". All self-compiled: OpenWrt x86_64, gtk3 - 3.22.21-1, lxterminal - 0.3.2-1, fluxbox - 1.3.7-1. How debug?

Consequence is lxterminal window cannot be moved, resized and has no title bar

Thanks;

Answer (score 0):

Turns out the issue was fluxbox "system style" "bloe". Changing it to "Meta" restored ability to move and resize lxterminal window.

The "called gtk_widget_queue_resize() during size_allocate()" warnings still persist.